# How to Convert Byte Array to Image inside in Linq output List

Tags: c#, linq

How to do this inside in list (user.image = plugins.LoadImage(user.Image))
LoadImage is function which return image in the Form BitmapImage

```
 var query = (
                     from user in chatDBContext.tbl_User
                     select new
                         {
                         user.FirstName, user.LastName, user.Gender, user.Email,
                         user.DoB, user.Address, user.City, user.State,user.Country,
                         user.Quote, user.username, (user.image = plugins.LoadImage(user.Image))
                          }
                     ).ToList();
```

Comment: Is `user.image = plugins.LoadImage(user.Image)` not working for you? is it throwing any _error/exception_?

Comment: its give an error. An expression tree may not contain an assignment operator

Comment: It is `Linq to Sql`, this statement executes in the database. To fix this problem, move this Image conversion code outside. Just hold  `user.image = user.Image`.

Comment: My bad, use  `image = user.Image`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that `plugins.LoadImage(user.Image))` can't be executed in a linq2sql (nor EntityFramework) context.

So: execute the query first, take objects in memory (you can do that by call `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` for example), **then** retrieve the image.

```
// database oriented query 
var query = from user in chatDBContext.tbl_User
            select user;

// take objects in memory THEN retrieve images
var objects = query.ToList().Select(user => new
{
    user.FirstName, user.LastName, user.Gender, user.Email,
    user.DoB, user.Address, user.City, user.State,
    user.Quote, user.username, image = plugins.LoadImage(user.Image)
});
```

Consider that you can avoid repeat all `user` fields simply selecting the entire object instead all single properties:

```
var objects = query.ToList().Select(user => new
{
    user, image = plugins.LoadImage(user.Image))
});
```

Usage:

```
foreach (var obj in objects)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.user.FirstName);
    Console.WriteLine(obj.user.LastName);
    // and so on all user properties

    Console.WriteLine(obj.image.Height); // just example
}
```

---

**EDIT (clarification)**

in your source code there is 2 distinct problems:

1. You are trying to set the `user.image` property (i don't know if there is any property named `image` in your `User` class, anyway): **you can't** do an assignment into an anonymus object constructor. Instead, like my example or the other answer example, you should declare an `image` property right into the anonymus object initializer.

`new { user.image = plugins.LoadImage(user.Image) }`

should becomes

`new { image = plugins.LoadImage(user.Image) }`

2. You can't execute all C# code into a linq2sql (nor EntityFramework), only few methods are allowed, like `Convert.ToInt32()`, `.ToString()`, etc.

For more info about the code that **you can execute** into a linq2sql query take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386970.aspx), otherwise for EntityFramework [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = (from user in chatDBContext.tbl_User
                 select new
                     {
                     user.FirstName, user.LastName, user.Gender, user.Email,
                     user.DoB, user.Address, user.City, user.State,user.Country,
                     user.Quote, user.username, user.image = user.Image
                      }
                 ).ToList()
             .Select(c => new {
                     FirstName = c.FirstName, LastName = c.LastName, Gender = c.Gender, Email = c.Email,
                     DoB = c.DoB, Address = c.Address, City = c.City, State = c.State, Country = c.Country,
                     Quote = c.Quote, username = c.username, image = plugins.LoadImage(c.image)
                      }).ToList();
```